# My Laptop does not recognize the additional RAM, while CPU-Z does

Tags: memory

My laptop is ASUS X550JX with an additional RAM slot. I just upgraded it with RAM's specification as follow:

[image: additional RAM].

It was running well and dxdiag read 12 GB RAM (4+8). Then I realize, my laptop is suddenly getting slower and I found dxdiag reads 4 GB only, as well on the task manager. CPU-Z still reads my new RAM on the SPD tab (just like the image above) but, on tab memory reads 'single' channel like this

[image].

I have tried with my friend's RAM, and it's worked. I have unplugged my RAM and still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the built-in RAM:
`Capacity    DeviceLocator   FormFactor  Manufacturer  MemoryType  PartNumber        SerialNumber  Speed
4294967296  ChannelA-DIMM0  12          Samsung       24          M471B5173EB0-YK0  00000000      1600`